# Vaadin Router doesn't update the view

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a strange problem with the latest version of Vaadin.

I have a two simple views with a custom layout:

```
public class MyLayout extends AppLayout {

    public MyLayout() {
        this.addToNavbar(new RouterLink("View 1", View1.class));
        this.addToNavbar(new RouterLink("View 2", View2.class));
    }
}
```

```
@Route(value = "view1", layout = MyLayout.class)
@RouteAlias(value = "", layout = MyLayout.class)
public class View1 extends Div {

    public View1() {
        this.add(new Span("View 1"));
        this.add(new Button("Goto View 2", event -> UI.getCurrent().navigate(View2.class)));
    }
}
```

The View2's class is similar without the @RouterAlias annotation.

When I click on Goto View 2, the UI is updated with the View2's content. Then I navigate to View1 using the menu, the UI is not updated and still show View2 content.

I'm using Vaadin 15.0.4 with Spring Boot 2.2.6.

Here's a sample project : https://github.com/gronono/vaadin-bug-router

Edit : With Vaadin 14.1.25, I don't have the problem.

Comment: It seems like a bug. I reported it at https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/8071